# groovy file writer not able to keep format for large string

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to write a large yaml string to a yaml file using groovy. I'm able to create the new file but the content inside the file is not correct. it contains some extra brackets and the yaml after builder in the yaml file. is there a way to fix this?

```
import groovy.yaml.YamlBuilder

def builder = new YamlBuilder()

builder.yaml {
    apiVersion 'apps/v1'
    kind 'Deployment'
    metadata {
        name 'weblogic-testapp'
        namespace 'app'
        labels {
            app 'weblogic'
        }
    }
}
def output = builder.toString()
new File('deployment.yaml').write(output)
```

this is the output I get. it includes the yaml with curly brackets.

```
{yaml={apiVersion=apps/v1, kind=Deployment, metadata={name=weblogic-testapp, namespace=app, labels={app=weblogic}}}}
```

Comment: Could you please update the question, providing the expected result and what you get with your implementation? For me your code works ok, I'm not sure I understand what exactly is "not correct"?

Comment: I have added the output in the question. It would be great if you could help.

Comment: I do not think it is the output of the code. How comes that the data(apiVersion, kind) is completely different? Please post the real output of the code that you posted.

Comment: it's a sample output  just to show what type of ouput I'm getting. I can't share real code here ..so added sample output

Comment: The problem is that you share the code that works correctly and you show the incorrect output without code... how people suppose to guess where the problem is? :) Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have updated the output that I got by running this code.

Comment: Really strange. Your code produces different result for me. What is your OS, Java version. Groovy version? Could you also replace last two lines of your code with "println builder.toString()"? Let's at least see what Groovy itself is producing, before writing to the file.

Comment: I have already done it. the println prints valid yaml. but when I write it to the file and read it that's when I receive this weird response. OS is Linux, Groovy is 4 and Java is 17.

Comment: ok, couple of more questions: a) have you opened the file with nano, what is inside? b) "and read it" how do you read the file?